# Why do I keep getting NotImplementedError: multivariate partial fraction decomposition when using sympy.apart()?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find the inverse laplace transform of the equation:

```
X(s) = (s(s+2))/((s+2)(s+3)(s+4))*e^-2s.
```

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
sympy.init_printing()

s, t = sympy.symbols('s, t')

X = (((s*(s+1))/(s+2)*(s+3)*(s+4)))*(sympy.exp(-2*s))

parfrac = sympy.apart(X, full=True).doit()

def invL(X):
    return sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(X, s, t)

print(invL(X))
```

Above is what I have been trying and I keep getting "NotImplementedError: multivariate partial fraction decomposition"

how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: This link might help: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14763

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image. We want to see it in the question itself and have the opportunity to copy it.

Comment: This error is seen if you do not specify which variable to expand wrt e.g. `apart(expr)` bs `apart(expr, s)`.

Comment: It runs for me without the `exp(-2*s)` term.  Inclusion of `x=s`, changes the error.  `sympy` functions aren't guaranteed to work with all expressions.